# Can't do anything while impersonated with WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated

Tags: c#, impersonation

I use NegotiateStream to get client WindowsIdentity. It shows that user A successfully authenticated using Kerberos and TokenImpersonationLevel == Delegation. But when I try to do something it almost every time throws an error. If I try to use SqlClient it says that server is not found, if I try to use Process.Start it throw Win32Exception.

If I do the same things without impersonation, they work, if I do them with impersonation, they don't work. Can anybody help me getting it to work?

If I try to use Process.Start I get following error and stacktrace

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "Unknown error (0x2)"

```
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at Network_Communucation_Module.Server`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<AuthentificateClient>b__3() in D:\Modules\Network Communucation Module\Server.cs:line 155
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<>c__DisplayClass73_0.<RunImpersonatedInternal>b__0(Object <p0>)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Comment: What type of application are you running?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533

Comment: I am runnig .Net 5 console application for client and .Net 5 service using Topshelf on server

Comment: @GSerg, but if nothing works when impersonating, so how same things work for example in WCF?

Comment: This is sort of meaningless without showing 1) how you're calling things, 2) how you've set up your service accounts for delegation, and 3) what actual exceptions you're seeing, ideally with stacktrace.

Comment: If I try to use Process.Start I get following error and stacktrace